# Can grading tables be modified?

Tags: exam

The manual for the `exam` class says:

> The `exam` document class can print a grading table, indexed either by
>   question number or by page number. (p. 78)

I'm writing an exam with forty multiple-choice questions, machine-scored, and three open-response questions, manually scored. So neither of those options suits me. What I need is a table indexed by question type, or possibly by section or subsection. In other words:

```
Section | Poss. score | Actual score|
=====================================
MC      |           40|             |
-------------------------------------
Essay 1 |           20|             |
-------------------------------------
Essay 2 |           20|             |
-------------------------------------
Essay 3 |           20|             |
-------------------------------------
```

Can this be done? It doesn't seem to fit either of the existing schemes, because it aggregates all the multiple choice questions into one row but lists each open response separately. Below is the only solution I have thought of; it does create the table I want, but (a) it numbers the MC section as question 1, which I don't want, and (b) it requires me to put a dummy question in the essay section, which I also don't want.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}



\begin{document}


    \begin{coverpages}

        \begin{center}

            \huge

            Final Exam\\
            English 213\\
            June 19, 2017\\

            \vspace{1in}

            Your name:\dotfill

            \vspace{1in}

            \settabletotalpoints{100}

            \partialgradetable{myrange}[v][questions]



        \end{center}


    \end{coverpages}


    \section*{Open response (60 points)}


    \begin{questions}

        \begingradingrange{myrange}

            \question [40] MC

            \question [20] Who's the better leader: Odysseus or Ralph? Why? Refer to both texts, as specifically as your memory allows.

            \question [20] Who makes the transition to adulthood more successfully: Holden or Telemachus?

            \question [20] In this year's texts, who makes successful moral choices? Who doesn't? Why?


        \endgradingrange{myrange}



    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

## Update

The `titledquestion` command deals with the first issue (the MC section labeled as ``question 1'' in the table), since I can list `\titledquestion{Multiple Choice}[40]` and so forth. I still have not been able to figure out the other issue (a dummy question in the list of essay questions).

Comment: @CarLaTeX I am duly chastened. See above.